# Trying to get Guice servlets working. What am I missing?

Tags: java, jetty, guice

I'm trying out Guice as a lightweight alternative to Spring DI for a personal project.  I have the following code:

```
@WebListener
public class ApplicationInitializer extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationInitializer.class);

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        log.info("Setting up Guice");
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule(){

            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                serve("*.html").with(DefaultServlet.class);
                log.info("Configured servlets");
            }
        });
        return injector;
    }
}
```

And then the following servlet:

```
@Singleton
public class DefaultServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultServlet.class);

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("Got to servlet");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

I see the two log lines in the first code snippet in my logs, but I can't get the servlet to respond.  I'm not sure if I'm missing config, but I can't find an example with any more significant code than this...

What URL would you expect to work?  I've configured this to run in Jetty with the root application context path, so I'd expect the following to work:

http://localhost:8080/index.html

All I can get is a 404.  I never see the log line in the servlet.

**Update**: this code works if I embed a Jetty server and start it in main().  What is so different about running it in a servlet container?

Comment: What does your `web.xml` look like?

Comment: I don't have one.  The @WebListener annotation is what I was trying to use to bootstrap the app.  The app gets to the 'Configured servlets' line in the code above. However, I could well be missing something else from the web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My previous answer was wrong. It *is* possible to write a simple adapter for the GuiceFilter class that allows us to annotate it with @WebFilter, and that *does* allow us to completely do away with web.xml in Guice web apps.  See below:

```
@WebFilter(value="/*", initParams= {})
public class GuiceFilterAdapter extends GuiceFilter {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        super.init(filterConfig); 
    }
}
```